# Photo Competition 2021-07-05: Street Photography

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: Street Photography

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_photography) says it quite well:

> A type of documentary photography that features subjects in candid
> situations within public places such as streets, parks, beaches,
> malls, political conventions and other settings.

This theme was suggested by [Vian Esterhuizen](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/4124/vian-esterhuizen).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/125278/photo-competition-2021-07-05-street-photography?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on July 5, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Indifference

[image: Indifference]

PANASONIC LUMIX GX10 
F10
1/400
31mm
ISO 200

Comment: Indifference, it made me look twice and smiled

Answer (score 7):

### 37 Pieces of Flair

[image: Fabulous]

On a photography walkabout to downtown NYC 2017-06-24 4:27pm, saw this lady who could give Brian a run for his money.

Nikon D700, Nikkor 80-400mm

f9 1/200s ISO 3200 @ 800mm (using a 2x teleconverter)

Converted to B&W in Photoshop plus an emulated split contrast double exposure for depth.

Comment: She definitely doesn't just want to do the bare minimum

Comment: @scottbb I was a little nervous nobody would get the reference to a 22 year old cult classic :)

Answer (score 7):

### I'm Moo-vin' On

[image]

The parade had passed moving right to left earlier in the evening. About forty-five minutes after the end had snaked by the Princess Theatre and continued another mile or so to the end of the route this entrant drove by retracing the path from whence it had come.

Canon EOS 5D Mark II + EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS.
ISO 3200, f/4, 1/160.

December 3, 2012. Decatur, Alabama.

Answer (score 4):

### Pennies in the Fountain

[image]

On a photography walkabout to midtown NYC 2018-07-08 4:25pm. The boy was asking his mother for pennies to throw into the South Fountain in Madison Square Park

f5.6 1/320s ISO 200

Converted to B&W in Photoshop plus an emulated split contrast double exposure for depth.

Answer (score 4):

### Sidewalk Sugar Skull

An artist is almost done painting a sugar skull design on the face of a girl as twilight falls over a Friday Night street festival in Decatur, AL on 15 July, 2016.

[image: Sugar Skull]

Canon EOS 5D Mark III + EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS @ 105mm, ISO 3200, 1/160, f/4.5

The primary light source was a small lamp over the artist's shoulder she uses to help see her client's faces as she works. There was also a mix of ambient twilight and streetlights. Exposing for the lamp effectively killed much of the ambient. Raw conversion and significant post-processing was done using Canon's *Digital Photo Professional 4*.

Answer (score 4):

### Tinkerbell Takes a Peek

[image]

A young lady costumed as the 'Peter Pan' character Tinkerbell glances at her reflection in a door glass as she walks past during late afternoon at a street fair in Decatur, Alabama (USA) on 16 August, 2019.

Canon EOS 7D Mark II + EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II @ 200mm, ISO 100, f/3.5, 1/500.

Cropped to a 3:4 aspect ratio and downsized to 1800x2400 to meet the SE file size limit.

Answer (score 2):

### Los Gatos Muertos

Los Gatos, California - February 10th 2020

iPhone 7+, f/2.8, 1/120, ISO-40

I saw two dead cats when I was biking to school. I quickly hopped off my bike and took a picture.

[image]

Comment: Everyone, please respect the contest rules and don't downvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### A formal sendoff

Taken opposite Royal Thai Police headquarters at Rama I road in Bangkok. The policeman pictured followed the car across the street. Presumably, there's a high-ranking officer onboard as it's a luxury car with the emergency lights on (barely visible on the grill of the car). After stopping traffic on both sides allowing the car to cross the street, he gave a sendoff salute (pictured).

The picture was taken in April of 2021. I used my Sony RX10M3 at f/4, 1/125 second exposure, 38.04mm and ISO500.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Crash

June 27th 2021, California

Nikon D500 with Nikkor 18-140

1/1000, f/6.3, ISO2016, 62mm

[image]

Was driving back home from Sequoia National Park, and snapped this pic of a crash as we were going on the highway.